# how to place customWidget in table calendar in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am using table calendar for showing a perticular month.

Here i want to replace day number with my custom widget that will expense of that day,

i am sure this package has facility to provide custom widget to replace day

like

1         2
389.0    4903.0

```
  Map<int,double> myMap={
    1:200.00,
    2:400.00,
    3.500.00,
    ....
  };
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TableCalendar(
      headerVisible: false,
      // daysOfWeekVisible: true,
      focusedDay: DateTime(year,month,1),
      firstDay: DateTime(year,month,1),
      lastDay: DateTime(year,month + 1, 0), // This will return last day of current month
      //startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.monday,
      //availableGestures: AvailableGestures.none,
      //daysOfWeekHeight: 20,
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use custom builder of table_calendar, `calendarBuilders`.

Below is sample code, code your logic of **getExpenseFor** function.

```dart
return TableCalendar(
  ...,
  calendarBuilders: CalendarBuilders(
    defaultBuilder: (context, day, focusedDay) {
      final expense = getExpenseFor(day);
      return Center(
        child: Text(expense),
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

Comment: Thanks it worked..can u tell me one more thing...space between two week rows

Comment: Pleasure, use rowHeight.

Comment: your code working fine but its not showing custom widget on Current Date...it uses default widget for current date(i mean to today)

Comment: You could check several custom builders provided by table_calendar package. Cmd + left click (maybe Ctrl + left click for Window) CalendarBuilders.